# Application-defined error when adding a formula to a cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add an IF formula to a cell in excel using a macro and it is displaying a 1004 application-defined or object-defined error for the .Range line. How can I prevent this error?

```
Sub AddFormula()
Dim Formula As Variant
 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Responses 1")
    .Range("CE2").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(OR((BZ2=""No"", BZ2=""0"")), BZ2, AN2), AN2)"

 End With
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: the issue is that your formula is not a valid formula - specifically the OR bit

Comment: Thank you perfect, it was the bracket after the OR that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that the formula you supplied is not valid. There are too many brackets in the OR part.

try this instead

```
Sub AddFormula()
Dim Formula As Variant
 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Form Responses 1")
.Range("CE2").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(OR(BZ2=""No"", BZ2=""0""), BZ2, AN2), AN2)"

 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: BZ2=""0"" maybe that needs to be BZ2=0 as it will be an integer not a string

Comment: Thank you, I moved the bracket after the OR to before the OR and corrected the BZ2=0 and it works perfectly now